# How to find number of triplets?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility

Let $S=\{1,2,3....50\}$ ,$x<y<z$  and $xyz$ is divisible by $125$.

What are the possible triplets $(x,y,z)?$
How to think about this question?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$125=5\times5\times5$. So there must be multiples of $5$ among $x,y,z$ such that $5$ occurs atleast three times in prime factorization overall.